# How To Change Value on selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code and working fine.but i want to add it on leave type selection
when leave type selected then its shows the count and when leavetype is shortleave then count should be 0.25 and when half day then 0.50.and otherwise work normally any body can help me in this regard..thanks in advance

```
<form>    

    Leave Type:
    <select id="filter" name="leavetype" required>
                  <option value="selected">Select Leave Type</option>
                  <option value="Absent" >Absent</option>
                  <option value="Annual" >Annual</option>
                  <option value="Medical" >Medical</option>
                  <option value="Casual" >Casual</option>
                  <option value="LWOP" >LWOP</option>
                  <option value="Short Leave" >Short Leave</option>
                  <option value="Half Day" >Half Day</option>
                  </select>
    <br> Leave From Date
    <input type="text" id="leavefromdate">
    <br> Leave To Date
    <input type="text" id="leavetodate">
    <br> Leave Count
    <input type="text" id="leavecount">
    <br>   

</form>    

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#leavefromdate,#leavetodate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        })

        $("#leavefromdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
        $("#leavetodate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });

        $('#leavetodate').change(function() {
            var start = $('#leavefromdate').datepicker('getDate');
            var end = $('#leavetodate').datepicker('getDate');

            if (start <= end) {
                var leavecount = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + 1;
                $('#leavecount').val(leavecount);
            }
            else {
                alert("You cant come back before you have been!");
                $('#leavefromdate').val("");
                $('#leavetodate').val("");
                $('#leavecount').val("");
            }
        }); //end change function
    }); //end ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps to achieve your requirement.

1. In Onchange event of leave type select : For "short leave" make leave
   count 0.25 and for "half leave" make leave count "0.50".
2. On selection of leave type "short leave" and "half leave" make
   "Leave From Date" field disable.
3. For any other leave type selection enable "Leave From Date" field and the calculation will be as it is.

For any other leavetype make the "Leave From Date" field enable and calculation will be as it is.

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").on("change",function(){
    var leaveType = $(this).val();
    if(leaveType=='Short Leave'){
      $('#leavecount').val(0.25);
      $('#leavetodate').prop("disabled",true);
      $('#leavetodate').val("");
    }else if(leaveType=="Half Day"){
      $('#leavecount').val(0.25);      
      $('#leavetodate').prop("disabled",true);
      $('#leavetodate').val("");
    }else{
      $('#leavetodate').prop("disabled",false);
    }
  });
  $( "#leavefromdate,#leavetodate" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  })

  $( "#leavefromdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  $( "#leavetodate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

  $('#leavetodate').change(function() {
    var start = $('#leavefromdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $('#leavetodate').datepicker('getDate');

    if (start<=end) {
      var leavecount   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24+1;
      $('#leavecount').val(leavecount);
    }
    else {
      alert ("You cant come back before you have been!");
      $('#leavefromdate').val("");
      $('#leavetodate').val("");
      $('#leavecount').val("");
    }  
  }); //end change function
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<form>    

  Leave Type:
  <select id="filter" name="leavetype" required>
    <option value="selected">Select Leave Type</option>
    <option value="Absent" >Absent</option>
    <option value="Annual" >Annual</option>
    <option value="Medical" >Medical</option>
    <option value="Casual" >Casual</option>
    <option value="LWOP" >LWOP</option>
    <option value="Short Leave" >Short Leave</option>
    <option value="Half Day" >Half Day</option>
  </select>
  <br> Leave From Date
  <input type="text" id="leavefromdate">
  <br> Leave To Date
  <input type="text" id="leavetodate">
  <br> Leave Count
  <input type="text" id="leavecount">
  <br>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the values accordingly..

```
<select id="filter" name="leavetype" required>
     <option value="selected">Select Leave Type</option>
     <option value="Absent" >Absent</option>
     <option value="Annual" >Annual</option>
     <option value="Medical" >Medical</option>
     <option value="Casual" >Casual</option>
     <option value="LWOP" >LWOP</option>
     <option value="0.25" >Short Leave</option>
     <option value="0.5" >Half Day</option>
</select>
```

and while getting value from dropdown, now you get the count as value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Just add values to your options, or check for the strings like so:

```
var leavefactor = 1;
      if ($("select#filter").val() == 'ShortLeave') {leavefactor = 0.25;} else if($("select#filter").val() == 'HalfDay') {leavefactor = 0.5;}
      $('#leavecount').val(leavecount * leavefactor);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#leavefromdate, #leavetodate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  })

  $("#leavefromdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
  $("#leavetodate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });

  $('#leavetodate').change(function() {
    var start = $('#leavefromdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#leavetodate').datepicker('getDate');

    if (start <= end) {
      var leavecount = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + 1;
      var leavefactor = 1;
      if ($("select#filter").val() == 'ShortLeave') {
        leavefactor = 0.25;
      } else if ($("select#filter").val() == 'HalfDay') {
        leavefactor = 0.5;
      }
      $('#leavecount').val(leavecount * leavefactor);
    } else {

      alert("You cant come back before you have been!");
      $('#leavefromdate').val("");
      $('#leavetodate').val("");
      $('#leavecount').val("");
    }
  }); //end change function
}); //end ready
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="filter" name="leavetype" required>
    <option value="selected">Select Leave Type</option>
    <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
    <option value="Annual">Annual</option>
    <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
    <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
    <option value="LWOP">LWOP</option>
    <option value="ShortLeave">Short Leave</option>
    <option value="HalfDay">Half Day</option>
  </select>
  <br>Leave From Date
  <input type="text" id="leavefromdate">
  <br>Leave To Date
  <input type="text" id="leavetodate">
  <br>Leave Count
  <input type="text" id="leavecount">
  <br>



</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add change event for your dropdown filter and onChange event you ca trigger and change leave count value like below.

```
$('#filter').on('change', function (e) {

    var valueSelected = this.value;
    var value ;
   switch(valueSelected ) {
    case "Half Day":
        vaule =  $('#leavecount")val();
        value =  value/2;
        $('#leavecount")val(value);
        break;
    case "Short Leave":
        vaule =  $('#leavecount")val();
        value =  value/4;
        $('#leavecount")val(value);
        break;
    default:
        default ;
}


});
```